# How to expand toggle sidebar more

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the following HTML + CSS for a sidebar on a asp.net web page. I got this from a template. Currently when I toggle the sidebar, it comes out messed up. The text and icon are not in the same line. I think it is running out of space. How can i change it so that when it is toggled, it opens up more? Thank you. I'm really new to CSS and bootstrap. Thank you.

```
   <div id="wrapper">      
      <!-- Sidebar -->
            <!-- Sidebar -->
      <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav" id="sidebar">    
           <li class="sidebar-brand"><a id="menu-toggle" href="#">Menu<span id="main_icon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span></a></li> 
          <li><a>Dashboard<span class="sub_icon glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span></a></li>
          <li><a>Reports<span class="sub_icon glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span></a></li>
            <li><a>Configuration<span class="sub_icon glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span></a></li>
            <li><a>Settings<span class="sub_icon glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <!-- Page content -->
      <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="page-content inset">
          <div class="row">
                    <div>
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="body" runat="server">
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
.row{
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
}

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 70px;
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
    height: 100%
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: -150px;
    left: 70px;
    width: 150px;
    background: #222;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}

.sidebar-nav {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
#wrapper.active {
    padding-left: 150px;
}
#wrapper.active #sidebar-wrapper {
    left: 150px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

#sidebar_menu li a, .sidebar-nav li a {
    color: #999;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 150px;
    background: #252525;
    border-top: 1px solid #373737;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1A1A1A;
    -webkit-transition: background .5s;
    -moz-transition: background .5s;
    -o-transition: background .5s;
    -ms-transition: background .5s;
    transition: background .5s;
}
.sidebar_name {
    padding-top: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: .7;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  line-height: 40px;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  color: #999999;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

.sidebar-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

#main_icon
{
   float:right;
   padding-right: 30px;
   padding-top:20px;
}
.sub_icon
{
   float:right;
   padding-right: 32px;
   padding-top:10px;
}
.content-header {
  height: 65px;
  line-height: 65px;
}

.content-header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  line-height: 65px;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
    #wrapper {
    padding-left: 70px;
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
    left: 70px;
}
#wrapper.active {
    padding-left: 150px;
}
#wrapper.active #sidebar-wrapper {
    left: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}
}



    .glyphicon{
        font-size: 19px;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#wrapper").toggleClass("active");
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll just need to make some updates to the CSS to make it wider. These are the selectors I made changes to. You can see the working version in the Fiddle below.

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: -242px;
    left: 70px;
    width: 250px;
    background: #222;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}

#wrapper.active #sidebar-wrapper {
    left: 66px;
}

.sidebar-nav {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 70px;
        transition: all .4s ease 0s;
    }
    #sidebar-wrapper {
        left: 70px;
    }
    #wrapper.active {
        padding-left: 150px;
    }
    #wrapper.active #sidebar-wrapper {
        left: 242px;
        /*width: 150px; You can remove this */
        transition: all .4s ease 0s;
    }
}
```

[Check out this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mikehomme/o0o4424w/2/)

Comment: I can see the icons correctly but when I toggle the sidebar, I don't see the corresponding tab names in the sidebar.

Comment: @sparta93 In the fiddle or did you update your code? What browser?

Comment: If i resize the output window in the fiddle to very small, it works with your code. if I make the output window big, it does not work. I'm using chrome. Same problem with my updated code as well.

Comment: @sparta93 Just updated the fiddle, changed `#wrapper.active #sidebar-wrapper { left: 66px; } `. Working now?

Comment: thank you so much. that works. However, something else stopped working... the content to the right of the sidebar inside the `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` is not getting resized properly when the sidebar is opened. Ideally, it would resize and fill the space on the right. right now the sidebar cuts off the left portion of the content area.

Comment: @sparta93 Sounds like you may need to adjust some of the CSS for the PlaceHolder? I can't really help if I can't see it.

Comment: @sparta93 If you can fork the Fiddle I created and reproduce the problem with contents of the placeholder in it, I'll have a look.

Comment: I don't have any css for the placeholder, instead I think the `page-content-wrapper' is being used from the CSS above and sure, ill fork and reproduce the issue.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mfgm13a8/4/ you can check by toggling the sidebar on and off. Ideally, the picture should take up all space to the right of the sidebar and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121379/discussion-between-sparta93-and-pmahomme).